# Execution never end in query with case condition in select

Tags: mysql

I need to execute a query contains a case with a subquery in conditions.
That's the query

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM   `contatti_t_interazioni` `iz`
                      WHERE  `iz`.`id_interesse` = `i`.`id_interesse`) THEN "si"
         ELSE "no"
       end AS `Interazioni`
FROM   ((((`contatti_t_interessi` `i`
          LEFT JOIN `contatti_t_proposte` `p`         ON(( `i`.`id_interesse` = `p`.`id_interesse` )))
          LEFT JOIN `v_anagrafica_utenti` `a`         ON(( `i`.`id_utente` = `a`.`id` )))
          LEFT JOIN `contatti_tlk_statointeresse` `si ON(( `i`.`stato_interesse` = `si`.`id_statointeresse` )))
          LEFT JOIN `v_anagrafica_utenti` `ar`        ON(( `i`.`id_referente` = `ar`.`id` )))
WHERE  ( `a`.`id` > 0 )
GROUP  BY `i`.`id_interesse`
UNION
SELECT CASE
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM   `contatti_t_interazioni` `iz`
                      WHERE  `iz`.`id_interesse` = `i`.`id_interesse`) THEN "si"
         ELSE "no"
       end AS `Interazioni`
FROM   ((((`contatti_t_interessi` `i`
          LEFT JOIN `contatti_t_proposte` `p`          ON(( `i`.`id_interesse` = `p`.`id_interesse` )))
          LEFT JOIN `contatti_t_esteri` `ce`           ON(( `i`.`id_contattoestero` = `ce`.`id_contattoestero` )))
          LEFT JOIN `contatti_tlk_statointeresse` `si` ON(( `i`.`stato_interesse` = `si`.`id_statointeresse` )))
          LEFT JOIN `v_anagrafica_utenti` `ar`         ON(( `i`.`id_referente` = `ar`.`id` )))
WHERE  ( `ce`.`id_contattoestero` > 0 )
GROUP  BY `i`.`id_interesse`;
```

when I try to execute that query it doesn't show me any errors but query execution never end.

What's the problem? I use the union because of other select attributes that I hide because the query is so long.

Sorry for my english, I hope you understand what I'm asking for.

Thank you

Comment: Oh dear. And you cant simply split this in a few queries, for you know, maintainability and debugging?

Comment: This looks like a best of a query, and if your tables are fairly large, then I can easily imagine this taking a long time.  You should spend some time learning about indices and optimizing queries.

Comment: Have you tried to inspect the execution plan?

Comment: I'm not the creator of the query, I'm just adding this new field.

Comment: the query is quite fast before containing the field I'm trying to add, I think there's something wrong with the union, but I'm not advanced in strong query and I'm not able to find the problem.

Comment: Which field are you adding?

Comment: This one CASE
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM   `contatti_t_interazioni` `iz`
                      WHERE  `iz`.`id_interesse` = `i`.`id_interesse`) THEN "si"
         ELSE "no"
       end AS `Interazioni`

Comment: You can improve the query removing the `*` from the query `SELECT * FROM contatti_t_interazioni` and change it for some arbitrary value, like `SELECT 1 FROM ...`  And another thing is... `iz`.`id_interesse` = `i`.`id_interesse`.... is very common mistake compare different types... are you sure those fields are the same data type?

Comment: I tried to change * to 1 but that's the same result then before. Yeah, iz.id_interesse and i.id_interesse same datatype